# удаление дубликатов значений в массиве

Tags: javascript

Есть массив

```
var array = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'three', 'one'];
```

и нужно удалить дубликаты значений, если таковы есть, что бы в данном примере получилось

```
var array = ['one','two','three'];
```

Пробовал так, но удаляется каждый второй

```
for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++){       
    var compare = array[i];           
    for (var j=0; j<array.length; j++){            
        if (compare == array[j]){
           delete data_search[j];
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: [Здесь](https://learn.javascript.ru/array-methods#оставить-уникальные-элементы-массива) посмотрите.

Comment: ES6 `function uniq(a) {
   return Array.from(new Set(a));
}`

Answer (score 3):

```
function unique(arr) {
  var obj = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var str = arr[i];
    obj[str] = true; 
  }
  return Object.keys(obj); 
}
```

[Тут](https://learn.javascript.ru/array-methods#%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%22%D0%A2%D1%83%D1%82%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5%22) почитайте подробней.

Comment: А почему вы использовали именно обьекты а не чисто массивы и функции работы с ними? Какая вообще выгода использовать обьекты вместо массивов? Совершенно все можно повторить в обоих вариантах, верно?

Comment: @Levelleor, объект здесь выступает в качестве хэша, так как не позволяет добавить в себя несколько одинаковых свойств. Таким образом задача решается за один проход, в отличие от массива, где нужен еще один проход на каждый элемент для определения уникальности

Comment: мой выбор в сторону объектов сделан из-за простоты и скорости работы. Логика простая. массив  [key : value]  при встрече повторяющегося ключа просто перезаписывается значение. В малых массивах разница абсолютно не заметна.

Comment: @Grundy А какая логика работы обьекта? Массив это ключ-значение и по кругудо бесконечности, а обьекты это подобие классов в С++, они хранят значения в определенных "ключах"? По ссылке что вы прислали я не нашел много информации...

Comment: @Levelleor, Объект в javascript представляет собой обычный ассоциативный массив или, иначе говоря, "хэш".[тут подробней](https://learn.javascript.ru/object)

Comment: @Levelleor, массив - это _последовательность_ значения, а _ключ-значение_ это как раз объект. По аналогии с другими языками: объект - это словарь, а массив - частный случай объекта, когда ключами являются целые числа

Comment: @Shadow33, в яваскрипте нет ассоциативных массивов, потому что объекты не поддерживают ни одного свойства присущего массиву а так же ни одного метода, типа сортировки

Comment: @Grundy,Значит [тут](https://learn.javascript.ru/object) информация подана не совсем корректно?

Comment: @Shadow33, я считаю - да. Кстати, в статье тоже есть уточнение _Кстати, в других языках программирования такую структуру данных также называют «словарь» и «хэш»._ В принципе весь вопрос в терминологии. Обычно говоря про ассоциативный массив подразумевают что можно например получить его длину. либо вызвать метод для добавления/удаления значения, отсортировать значения. В яваскрипт объекте это не доступно по умолчанию

Comment: @Grundy Окей, спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Если использовать ES6:

```
function uniq(a) {
   return Array.from(new Set(a));
}

var array = ['one','two','three','one','two','one','three','one'];

console.log(uniq(array));
```

А можно также посмотреть кучу способов с [английского SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9229821), которые нет смысла здесь приводить ибо их очень много и они там подробно описаны

Comment: как-то скучно и не интересно :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var array = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'three', 'one'];
for (var i=array.length-1; i>=0; --i)
{       
    var compare = array[i];           
    for (var j=i-1; j>=0; --j)
    {            
        if (compare == array[j]){
           array.splice(j, 1);
           --i;
        }              
    }
}
```